# Move constructor on destructed object?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have a piece of code

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A & other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    A(A && other)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

A && f()
{
    return A();
}

int main() {
    A a = f();
}
```

I tried running it and the output turns out to be

```
Default constructor
Destructor
Move constructor 
Destructor
```

My question is Why is destructor is called before the moved constructor? Does this also mean that second object was constructed with a destroyed value ?

Comment: You should not return (rvalue-)reference of temporary variable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux this should be the answer

Comment: Both GCC and VC should produce a compiler warning for this even by default. In any case, both *can* warn you if you set the appropriate warning level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning a local variable from `A && f()` has the same problem as `A & f()`. They are both references. By the time you construct `a` in `main()`, the local variable has been destroyed. This results in a reference to a destroyed instance leading to undefined behavior.

If you want to move `A()` from `f()` to `a` in `main` simply return by value. Try using the following :

```
A f() {
    return A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `A` object was created in `f`'s call stack frame. So when `f` returns control to `main` all the stack objects which were created inside `f` would have to be destroyed. That's why the first destructor was called.

Comment: That's an implementation-centric description of what happens. From a language POV, what happens here is simply undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChristianHackl thanks for the details. I would like to read some more about this. Any references or links? :)

Comment: Well, not more than a simple Google search for "c++ undefined behaviour" would show up. However, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub may be a good start.